# Como funciona data-binding em AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Procurei por algo que me explica-se como  a mágica do data-binding acontece porém não encontrei.

Minha dúvida é como são propagados os dados da view para model, como ele consegue acompanhar as mudanças sem setters e getters?

Pesquisei por algo em javascript que possa monitorar as mudanças de objetos e váriaveis encontrei [Object.watch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch), ele poderia ser utilizado para fazer data-binding ?

Comment: Você está querendo criar seu AngularJS? tipo um knockoutJS?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Eu gostaria apenas de endender e ver se há métodos diferentes de fazer, eu tenho uma função própria que não vem tanto ao caso, que tenta fazer um data-binding, mas  não passa de um reference data tag ou outras pessoas chamam populate por que não monitora as alterações, pensei até que esta pergunta pudesse responder minha dúvida, mas so me deixou com mais dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97872/como-funciona-o-databinding-e-dirty-check-do-angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maioria dos sistemas de templates vinculam dados em apenas uma direção, que se funde com os componentes do modelo, e este por sua vez, executa uma saída na sua tela (isso é o evento data-binding padrão). Após esta fusão, ocorrem algumas mudanças no modelo ou parte dele (seções), que estão relacionadas a esta tela. Entretanto, este comportamento, não é automático como pressupõe-se ao ver isso ocorrendo na tela. E pior ainda, as alterações que o usuário faz na tela não são refletidos no modelo.

A grande jogada, está na mão do desenvolvedor, que tem que escrever o código que faz esta sincronia de maneira constante através do modelo e o mesmo retorna essa atualização para a tela (visão).

Acontece que no AngularJS, O ***data-binding*** funciona um pouco diferente:

Em aplicativos angulares de ligação de dados, a sincronização de dados é automática, entre os componentes do modelo e sua exibição (tela). A maneira que Angular implementa esta vinculação de dados, permite que você trate o modelo como um *single-source* da sua aplicação. O que você vê na tela é uma projeção do modelo a todo instante. Quando o modelo muda, a visão reflete esta mudança, e vice-versa.

Primeiro o modelo (a HTML empacotada, juntamente com qualquer marcação ou diretiva adicional) é compilado no navegador. A etapa de compilação produz uma exibição ao vivo. Quaisquer alterações na tela são imediatamente refletidas no modelo, e quaisquer mudanças no modelo são propagadas para a visão (tela). O modelo é justamente a única verdade absoluta do estado do seu aplicativo. Isso é feito para facilitar o modelo de programação para o desenvolvedor.

Você pode pensar na visão (tela) como uma simples projeção instantânea do seu modelo. Porque a tela é apenas uma projeção do modelo, e o controlador é completamente separado da tela.

É a visão (tela) que enxerga o controlador e que envia comandos para ele.

Pense que o modelo é um tipo de facilitador, e o controlador o cara que envia as ordens para ele, e o que o modelo "facilitar", será  refletido automaticamente na visão.

No [**site do Angular JS**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding), você encontra mais informações a respeito.